# Where to save "next pathname" if redirecting to Login in react-router?

Tags: react-router, react-router-redux, redux-saga

I use react-router and react-router-redux, I will redirect user to Login page if he tries to visit a page requiring logged in without logging in:

```
<Route path="/react/myprofile" component={MyProfile} onEnter={requireAuth} /></Route>


function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
   const state_user = store.getState().auth.user;
   if (!state_user) {
     console.log('not logged in, redirect')
     replace({
       pathname: '/react/login',
       state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
     })
   }
}
```

And after the user logs in, I will redirect the user to "/react/myprofile": in my redux-saga, I do the following:

```
const route_state = get routing state from the store;
redirectTo(route_state.locationBeforeTransitions.state.nextPathname);
```

As above, I have to retrieve the information from  `route_state.locationBeforeTransitions.state.nextPathname`, it is too verbose, and it seems strange to do as this.

I wonder if there is a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a selector to extract the relevent piece of state and use it with the `select` effect from inside your saga

```
// for example in some file selectors
export const nextPathSelector = state => ...

// in some sagas.js file
import { nextPathSelector } from './selectors'
import { call, select, ... } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* saga() {
  ...
  const nextPath = yield select( nextPathSelector )
  yield call(redirectTo, nextPath)
}
```

Using selectors makes your sagas independant from the state shape. And using the `select` effect you can test the logic of the saga without moking the whole store.  For example

```
const gen = saga()

assert.deepEqual(
   gen.next().value,
  select( nextPathSelector )
)

assert.deepEqual(
   gen.next('dummy-path').value,
   call(redirectTo, 'dummy-path')
)
```